# How to updating laravel to 5.5.39 from 5.5.32?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm a newbie laravel.

Currently, Laravel had released version 5.6, but my version is 5.5.32.

And some reason, I only want to updating to 5.5.39 from 5.5.32 and do not upgrade 5.6.

I run "composer update", I see a error message.

So pls help me.

Thank you

Comment: What error message?

Comment: What is the error message without that how do we help you buddy ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to update laravel framework to a specific version than you can easily do it as follows:-

1. Go to your composer.json file
2. There you will see in the "require" section as follows "laravel/framework": "5.5.32.*"
3. you just need to change it to  "laravel/framework": "5.5.39.*"
4. save the composer.json and run composer update.

That's it. composer will read require from composer.json and update your packages likewise.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green.